# How to Achieve New File Template on GitHub Using Query String Args?

Tags: github, github-api

If I provide this link to someone, it will take them to a page to create this file on GitHub (it may ask them to log in and fork first):

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/new/master/README2

I want to prefill the new file title and content like this:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/new/master/README2?title=ThisIsANewFile&Contents=HereIsSomeContent

But it does not seem supported. I POST to this URL would be even better to prefill.

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm trying to avoid the API if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-fill is only available for the filename, not the content of the file itself or any other metadata like commit messages, commit description. The last available update on this feature I believe is still: https://github.blog/2012-12-05-creating-files-on-github/

Hope this helps.